# Initialising a class member dependant on another class member

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

```
        class TestGet : public ::testing::Test 
        {
        protected:
            TestGet() 
                : _txHandle(11)
            {
                _interface.get = mockGet;
            }

            Interface_T _interface;
            Handle_T _txHandle;
            DB _db;
        };
```

If I change `DB` so that it only has the following constructor:

```
        explicit DB(Interface_T& _interface):
            _interface(interface)
        {
        }
```

Do I now need to declare `_db` using a `std::shared_ptr` in my `TestGet` class, initialising it with `_interface` in the constructor?

UPDATE:

The issue was that I had:

```
    private:
        Interface_T _interface;
```

in the DB class instead of a reference.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. What exactly is the problem? Would adding , DB(_interface) after _txHandle(11) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
TestGet()
: _interface()
, _txHandle(11)
, _db(_interface)
{
    _interface.get = mockGet;
}
```

It depends, though, whether the constructor of `DB` does anything non-trivial. As long as it just stores the reference, this should be fine. That is, `DB` should look like this:

```
struct DB
{
    Interface_T & _interface;
    explicit DB(Interface_T & interface) : _interface(interface) { }
};
```

If you need further initialization, you could either add an `init()` function to `DB`, or make an initialization function for `Interface_T` that you can use in the constructor of `TestGet`.

Comment: What if DB was to take ownership of _interface? In other words, if it stored interface by value instead of by reference?

Comment: @Baz: Then this would be an entirely different question :-) (Also, that' snot what "taking ownership" means.)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I now need to declare _db using a std::shared_ptr in my TestGet class

No, you can leave it as it is, but you'll have to initialize it in the initialization lists of all `TestGet` constructors.

```
 TestGet() :
 _txHandle(11),
 _db(someInterface)
 {
     _interface.get = mockGet;
 }
```